# How to display one record into multiple records based on ID column

Tags: sql

Probably very basic question but I have records like this

```
Value1- Value2- Value3- Value4- Value5- ID1
Value1- Value2- Value3- Value4- Value5- ID2
```

(Values 1 - 5 can be null)

I want to display it based on ID in this format:

```
ID1 - Value1
ID1 - Value2 
ID2 - Value1
```

etc for all values that are not null.

Thanks!

Comment: Search for UNPIVOT and your database type (eg sql server), thats what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Søren, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be :

```
 select ID,col
 from Table
 Unpivot
 (
   col for details in (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5)
 ) as UnPvt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try cross join with same entity and add conditions to avoid data redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you havent mentioned the database heres a general query if column "value" for each id has minimum no of values for each id

```
      SELECT ID, 
      CASE WHEN VALUE =VALUE1
      THEN VALUE END CASE,
      ..........
      CASE WHEN VALUE =VALUEN
      THEN VALUE END CASE
      FROM TABLE GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the DBMS, but if you are using DB2, try to use `LATERAL`.

```
Select             
  A.ID, A_Column_Value
From               
  YOUR_TABLE A ,     
  LATERAL          
     (VALUES       
        A.COLUMN1,   
        A.COLUMN2,   
        A.COLUMN3) As All_Values (A_Column_Value)
```

Comment: That's actually standard SQL, but it should be `values (a.column1), (a.column2), (a.column3)` - three rows with one column. Your query returns a single row with three columns

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name In DB2 (on IBM i)  it's works with this syntax, I'm sure, because I fitted my program SQL   ;)